# Creating a regex that doesn't have two characters match at the beginning of the string.

Tags: java, regex

How do I write a regex to capture a string that doesn't have US as first two characters in the string? For e.g. `CA some text`. This string should match the regex because it doesn't have US as the first two chars. But `US some text` shouldn't match the regex.

`^(\w{2})(.*?)$` is what I started with... but I wanted to exclude US as the first 2 chars.

Comment: What language are you using? Different languages support different features.

Comment: @Bryan it has the Java tag.

Comment: @WChargin: it didn't when I wrote that comment.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way of writing it:

```
^([^U]|U[^S]).*$
```

This means that the first character is not `'U'`, or when the first character is `'U'`, then the second character must not be `'S'`.

Answer (score 3):

Just add a negative lookahead:

```
^(?!US\b)(\w{2})(.*)$
```

(the question mark is not useful here because there is the end of the pattern after)

If you want only capture all the text and not the country in a specific group:

```
^(?!US\b).*$
```

(don't forget to double-backslash)

Comment: How do I capture the first two characters if they are not US ?

Comment: @Phoenix: with the first pattern, there is this capturing group:`(\w{2})`. if you are not sure to have to word characters you can replace it by `(.{2})`

Comment: I tried this in groovy,                                             def pattern = ~/^(?!US\\b)(\\w{2})(.*)$/
assert pattern.matcher("CA 123").matches() and it didn't match ?

Comment: @Phoenix: try `System.out.println("CA 123".matches("^(?!US\\b)(\\w{2})(.*)$"));` in your code. In my opinion, the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Casimir why do you add a "\\b" if you are already matching on "\\w" ?

Comment: @Phoenix: with `\\b` the pattern doesn't match `USEFUL` for example. I have put it in the lookahead, but you can put it after the `\\w{2}` as you prefer.

Comment: The pattern doesn't capture the group in 1 if i do a find() instead of matches on the pattern ?

Answer (score 1):

too often folks want to match a negative.  Instead test for a positive match and then your if branch is the failure branch.  for example.

### [FIDDLE](http://fiddle.re/4t806)

```
if(str.matches('^US.*$')){ 
    // fail 
    // or  
    // str.substring(2)
} else { 
   //pass 
}
```

it's a lot easier to write and maintain

Comment: Sure! But what about captures?

Comment: his question isn't clear which is why you have the two cases in your answer.  But in the `if` branch he would have `str.substring(2)`. i'll update answer